# Python multiprocessing list append in for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have zero experience with multiprocessing, but I'm trying to apply it to this function.

```
def overlap_check(x,y,z,radius,N):
   problematic=[]
   for pair in combinations(range(N),2):
       distance=sqrt((x[pair[0]]-x[pair[1]])**2+(y[pair[0]]-y[pair[1]])**2+(z[pair[0]]-z[pair[1]])**2)
       if distance<2*radius:
           problematic.append(pair[0])
   return list(set(problematic))
```

To explain what it does, I basically made N amount of spheres with radius R randomly distributed in a 3D space. (x,y,z) are the list of center coordinates. This function checks for spheres that overlap with each other by comparing the distance between all the spheres through a for loop. If there is an overlap, then the sphere is saved to "problematic" which is converted to set() and back to list() to erase any repetition.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can make this faster by using a list comprehension. Multiprocessing seems a bit unworthy to me in this scenario.

Comment: What investigations into `multiprocessing` have you done? What patterns available seem to fit your requirements?

Comment: @PApostol what sort of list comprehension?

Comment: @quamrana not much I'm afraid. I think I read somewhere saying pool is useful for for loops. What I basically want is the code to run through the for loop as quickly as possible and wondered if multiprocessing can help me

Comment: Yes, `map` can help you perform a `1:1` conversion of each element of a collection into another collection, but using multiple cores to allow real simultaneous calculations. (You would have to post process to filter out the results which don't apply).

Comment: @hbj you can populate `problematic` with a list comprehension instead of a for loop.

Comment: @PApostol Ah I see. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @quamrana I am still a bit confused about what 'map' and 'pool' can do. I understand that they can perform multiple simultaneous calculations, but can they gather the data into 'problematic', i.e. a single list?

Comment: See the first code snippet in the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). It shows how to create a Pool and use map to transform one list into another.

Comment: @quamrana I think I've been thinking my problem the wrong way. I was thinking of appending elements into `problematic` by condition but now that I think of it, maybe saving the entire list into a boolean is a better idea... Then using `pool` and `map` should be straightforward as it is shown in the docs. Thank you!